# XSLT - Select particular attributes from list of attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been building XSLT where the XML is transformed from one structure to another. But I am stuck at one point where I am supposed to select a particular attribute from a list of attributes. I will provide the input XML file and the desired output XML file below. Also, I will highlight where I need help with(XSLT)

**Input XML:**

```
<Names>

<Attributes>

<Name>FirstName</Name>

<Value>Bharath<Value/>

</Attributes>

<Attributes>

<Name>LastName</Name>

<Value>Srinivas<Value/>

</Attributes>


<Attributes>

<Name>MiddleName</Name>

<Value>T</Value>

</Attributes>

</Names>
```

**Desired output XML:**

```
<Names>

<Attributes>

<Name>FirstName</Name>

<Value>Bharath<Value/>

</Attributes>


<Attributes>

<Name>MiddleName</Name>

<Value>T</Value>

</Attributes>

</Names>
```

So I just want to know which xsl element will be used in such cases, where 2 of the 3 attributes will be selected.
Thanks in advance for the solution!!

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Fair enough. The issue is that I don't know which xsl element to be used to select 2 out of 3 attributes from the above XML input file

Comment: You named an element "Attributes"?   In xml you can name an element anything, but naming an element "Attributes" is really misleading.  An "attribute" is a property of an element.  For example, <person name='Onlyfor Surfing'/> , @name is an attribute of the element named "person".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When processing the 'Attributes' element, you need to check the value of the 'Name' element. If the value is not 'Lastname', copy the element.

```
    <xsl:template match="Attributes">
        <xsl:if test="Name != 'Lastname'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

You would need to include your XSL in your question. @William is correct - calling an element Attributes, Name or Value is very confusing.